# Como eliminar o ruído numa imagem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Em relação à imagem apresentada, eu quero deixar apenas bem visível o tronco principal e os ramos (secundários) da planta (tomateiro).

[image: Tomateiro]

Em função das minhas tentativas, o que me parece que dá resultados mais encorajadores é a redução da área da imagem, seguida da aplicação do detector de bordas Canny.

Só que ainda existe muito daquilo que eu penso que se possa chamar ruído.
Se eu conseguir eliminar aquelas muitas pequenas "manchas" brancas (ruído), ficaria praticamente só com as formas (bordas) dos ramos da planta, tal como pretendido.

Qual será a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Código:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

imagem = cv2.imread("tomat.jpg")

print(imagem.shape)

for y in range(0, 360):
   for x in range(0, 120):
       imagem[y, x] = (0,0,0)

for y in range(0, 360):
   for x in range(250, 480):
       imagem[y, x] = (0,0,0)

gris = cv2.cvtColor(imagem, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)     

# Aplicar suavizado Gaussiano
gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(gris, (5,5), 0)

# Detectamos los bordes con Canny
canny = cv2.Canny(gauss, 50, 150)

cv2.imshow("canny", canny)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: o opencv tem uma função chamada `normalize` eu uso ela no reconhecimento facial e resolveu boa parte do problema

Comment: você não quer só "eliminar o ruído". Você precisa passar a imaem por várias etapas de forma que ao final, tenha em destaque, as caraterísticas que te interessam.  O melhor é ler algum texto teórico, ou um curso sobre processamento de imagens, e ao lngo o estudo você descobre a sequencia de filtros que vai ser mais interessante aplicar pra chegar onde você quer.

Comment: Alternativamente, você pode abrir um editor de imagens com interface gráfica, como o GIMP, e ver, se atrave de manipulações interativas com vários filtros, consegue separar só o que te interessa-  aí anota os passos, e escreve um script que faz isso, chamando os mesmos filtros.

Answer (score 1):

O OpenCV fornece 4 técnicas para retirar o ruído, uma dela é a função `cv.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored()`.

Os parâmetros são: `(original,destino,7,21,h,hColor)`, em que `h` é o parâmetro que regula o filtro, valores grandes de `h` retiram bem o ruído, porém a imagem perde detalhe. Para o `hColor` é a mesma ideia do `h`.

```
imagem_dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(imagem,None,7,21,7,21)
cv2.imshow("Teste",imagem_dst)
```

[Você pode ver melhor os parâmetros aqui](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d79/group__photo__denoise.html#ga03aa4189fc3e31dafd638d90de335617)